# PostgreSQL JOIN SELECT null if record on one of both table not exist

Tags: postgresql, join

I am having 2 tables with data as below:

```
tableA
========
1
2
3
4
5

tableB
=======
1
3
5
6
8
9
```

With this query:

```
select
    coalesce(tA.id, null) as id_A,
    coalesce(tB.id, null) as id_B
from
    tableA tA
inner join tableB tB on
    tA.id = tB.id
```

And it currently outputs:

```
current result
==============
1|1
2|null
3|3
4|null
5|5
```

My expected result is:

```
expected result
===============
1|1
2|null
3|3
4|null
5|5
null|6
null|8
null|9
```

I wanted the `6`, `8`, and `9` values from `tableB` appearing despite `tableA` not having it. I have tried `LEFT JOIN`, `RIGHT JOIN`, `FULL OUTER JOIN` but it cannot give the results I expected. I suspect there is something on the `FROM` clause where I just choose `tableA`.

How I can get the expected result?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is basic [PostgreSQL FULL OUTER JOIN](https://www.postgresqltutorial.com/postgresql-tutorial/postgresql-full-outer-join/) clause

```
SELECT  tA.id as id_A,
        tB.id as id_B
FROM tableA tA
FULL OUTER JOIN tableB tB ON tA.id = tB.id;
```

https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=508afb6b251572d45c01e6ec174da2ba

Learn more on: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/queries-table-expressions.html

Answer (score 0):

FULL OUTER JOIN works just fine:

```
SELECT a.id AS a_id, b.id AS b_id
FROM tablea a
FULL OUTER JOIN tableb b ON (a.id = b.id);
```